# How to set asset{{}} in Laravel to folder outside the project

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-7

I have three Laravel 7.x projects on a server that have same css,js,media and related files,
I want to set asset on the projects to a folder in project_one

```
--project_one
       |
       ---public
            |
            ----media
--project_two
       |
       ---public
          |
          ----{link to media folde in project one via ASSET_URL or other solution}
--project_three
       |
       ---public
          |
          ----{link to media folde in project one via ASSET_URL or other solution}
```

The media folder on all the projects are same and will be same for next projects, so I want to link this media file through asset() or is there any other solutions.
Has anyone idee on how to that!?.
thanks

Comment: have you tried setting the `ASSET_URL` env variable?

Comment: ASSET_URL needs to have fully qualified address, otherwise does not works @lagbox

Comment: do you actually want all of this served from a single base url or do you just want to link these files so they are accessible via each projects url?

Comment: It doesn't matter realy , i want somehow access the files. @lagbox

Answer (score 0):

Inside **config folder -> app.php**
Update following like and replace **null** with the url of asset folder.

```
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```

Comment: How should I write url
I mean , should I write like linux directories or fully-qulified project address???

Comment: @Izadpanah the URL (ASSET_URL)